# Postgres: What does @@ (double at symbol) mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently I've found a piece of code for ruby on rails which should search string like `like`-operator:

```
scope :search, -> (query) { where('name @@ :q', q: query) }
```

But couldn't find any documentation about it.

The operator doesn't work as expected. So what exactly it does?

Comment: text search in the column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a text search, [check out documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH).

If you'd rather not go somewhere else for an answer, here:

The `@@` operator in PostgreSQL is related to the full-text search capabilities provided by the tsquery and tsvector types. The `@@` operator is used to compare a tsquery value (the query) with a tsvector value (the document) to determine if the document matches the query.

The tsvector type represents a document processed for full-text search, while the tsquery type represents a query in a format suitable for searching in tsvector documents. The `@@` operator returns true if the query matches the document, and false otherwise.